# ActionScript - Receiving Name of Calling Function or Constructor?

Tags: actionscript-3, call

long shot:  is it possible to get the name of a calling function or the constructor from the called function?  is it possible to determine the previous function of the thread?

i would like to call some setter functions from my constructor and have my setter functions determine if it was the constructor that called them.

currently, i'm setting a boolean for this functionality, but perhaps there is another way?

```
public function Constructor(myNumber:Number)
     {
     this.myNumber = myNumber;
     }

public function set myNumber(value:Number):void
     {
     myNumberProperty = value;

     //if constructor called this, return;
     //else do some other stuff;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from liveDocs:

> Unlike previous versions of ActionScript, ActionScript 3.0 has no arguments.caller property. To get a reference to the function that called the current function, you must pass a reference to that function as an argument. An example of this technique can be found in the example for arguments.callee.

It was in AS2.0... It unfortunately throws an error if done in AS3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should be able to do this by generating an error and getting its stack trace. The constructor will have to be on that stack trace.

```
try
{
    throw new Error();
}
catch (e:Error)
{
    // parse this for the constructor name
    trace(e.getStackTrace());
}
```

That would be for detecting where a function call came from...

I would still go for your solution (setting the flag), as it's more oop and probably far faster in terms of performance.

Comment: i should have stated that i'm looking for a reference at runtime.  getStackTrace() is only available during debugging.  but i will take your advice and use the flag since anything that could do this would be probably much slower.  thanks.